# Understanding the eval() function of php

Tags: php, merge, eval

I'm a designer trying to upgrade myself into a coder-designer. Lately I've been looking into some PHP codes and manuals, then I ran into an example code for the `eval()` function :

```
<?php
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
echo $str. "\n";
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str. "\n";
?>
```

This is an example code of `eval()` function in official PHP website, and although it did help me understand the `eval()` function, I can't figure out how the example code works. to be more specific, I can't understand why

```
("\$str = \"$str\";")
```

results in a merged string.

I really can't figure out why this should work.

Comment: $str before being eval holds two non-variables ($string and $name) as they are strings, not variables. Through eval you are evaluating the $str (the part after '=') and assigning it again to $str (the part before '='). That's the reason why when echoing you get the complete string $str with $string and $name with their actual values. Have you tried changing the eval into eval("$str")?

Comment: When you're echoing the string $str via `echo $str. "\n";`, it gets handled as a normal string. That means `$string` and `$name` are not handled as variables but a normal string. 
The eval() function handles the string accordingly as a "php-code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what we have:

```
eval("\$str = \"$str\";")
```

Look, the string is in double quotes: it means that the `$` character will be interpreted as a variable start. So we screen this character with a backslash: `\$`, then it will "mean" just a normal dollar sign. Also, the double quotes inside the string had to be screened too.

In the end we are getting this string: (I changed the quotes to single so `$` dont confuse you): `'$str = "$str";'`. Look, it looks more like a normal code now :)

Evaling it, PHP will do the following (I removed the outer quotes for convenience):

```
eval( $str = "$str" );
```

Notice the double quotes here, too. It means that the variable inside, again, will be parsed/interpreted.

As `$str` was originally == `'This is a $string with my $name in it.'`, it will be inserted into the expression, and now it will look like:

```
$str = "This is a $string with my $name in it.";
```

And, again, double quotes! It parses and substitutes variables `$name` and `$string`, giving us at the end:

```
$str = "This is a cup with my coffee in it."
```

Voila!
A mindbreaker, but a really good example to learn the mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks all for the answer. This really helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

you should get two console.log like this

```
This is a $string with my $name in it.';

This is a $cup with my $coffe in it.';
```

Why? well first you print the value, of `$str` , **without** eval, and later, you eval them, basically this happens,

**First.**

Print `$str`, without eval.

`This is a $string with my $name in it.';`

**Second**

this piece of code, runs  `eval("\$str = \"$str\";");`

Eval replace  `$string` and `$name`. with the 2 new variables values, which are `$cup` and `$coffe`

Hope you get it